# Delphi 7, Chromiun (CEF3) не поддерживает форматы MP3 и MP4

Tags: delphi, mp3

Я понимаю, что форматы mp3 и mp4 закрытые. Но мне необходимо доработать компонент [CEF3](https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3/tree/2454), чтобы все-таки обеспечить поддержку форматов mp3 и mp4. Пожалуйста, поделитесь своим опытом или идеями. Говорят, можно взять библиотеку в Chrome браузере и ее как-то прикрутить...

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: С чего вы решили, что это закрытые форматы?

Comment: На счет закрытости форматов. В этом контексте, возможно, я некорректно написал о закрытости. Но сути проблемы это не меняет. Собрав тестовый проект в Delphi 7 использовав TChromiun (CEF3), столкнулся с проблемой проигрывания форматов MP3 и MP4. Может кто-то знает как решить эту проблему? Может нужно какие-то плагины подключить?